# Multiple plot sections within a single plot with an extended x axis

Tags: r, plot

Let assume some random data.

```
y<-rnorm(1000)
x<-rnorm(1000,1,2)
x1<-rnorm(1000,1,2)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(y,x,ylim=c(-4,4),xlim=c(-4,4))
plot(y,x1,ylim=c(-4,4),xlim=c(-4,4))
```

The above code produces two plots the one next to other. I would like the two separate plots to be part of the same plot with an extended or doubled x axis. So as to end up with something like,

[image: Single plot with extended x axis]

Is there a predefined way to perform such a task that I might be missing?